# $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=2}^{n}\cos^{-1}\frac{1+\sqrt{(k-1)(k)(k+1)(k+2)}}{k(k+1)}$ is equal to $\frac{120\pi}{m}$

Tags: integration, limits

If the value of $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=2}^{n}\cos^{-1}\frac{1+\sqrt{(k-1)(k)(k+1)(k+2)}}{k(k+1)}$ is equal to $\frac{120\pi}{m}$,find the value of $m$.

$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=2}^{n}\cos^{-1}\frac{1+\sqrt{(k-1)(k)(k+1)(k+2)}}{k(k+1)}=$

To convert this question into Riemann integral, I need $\frac{1}{n}\to dx$ and $\frac{k}{n}\to x$. How should I convert this limit of sum into integral,please help me.

Comment: https://www.khanacademy.org/math/integral-calculus/indefinite-definite-integrals/riemann-sums/v/riemann-sums-and-integrals

Comment: @SanchayanDutta,i know basics of it.But i am not able to apply them here.I tried.

Comment: If you don't mind..what is the source of this problem?

Comment: First of there cannot be a variable k in the answer!!

Comment: Just to clarify things, I suppose the k asked in the problem and the one in the integral are different?

Comment: I guess so.....@AritraDas

Comment: Answer is $k= 720$

Comment: amswer is 720.Let me edit to eliminate the confusion.

Comment: @juantheron i'd love to see your method!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let  $$\displaystyle S_{n} = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sum^{n}_{k=2}\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{(k-1)k(k+1)(k+2)}}
{k(k+1)}\right)\;$$

Now Let $$\displaystyle T_{k} = \cos^{-1}\left[\frac{1}{k}\cdot \frac{1}{k+1}+\frac{\sqrt{(k-1)k(k+1)(k+2)}}
{k(k+1)}\right]\;$$

Now Let $\displaystyle x=\frac{1}{k}$ and $\displaystyle y=\frac{1}{k+1}$

So $$\displaystyle \sqrt{1-x^2} = \sqrt{1-\frac{1}{k^2}} = \frac{\sqrt{(k-1)(k+1)}}{k}$$ and

$$\displaystyle \sqrt{1-y^2} = \sqrt{1-\frac{1}{(k+1)^2}} = \frac{\sqrt{k(k+2)}}{k+1}$$

So $\displaystyle T_{k}$ is of the form $$\cos^{-1}\left(xy+\sqrt{1-x^2}\sqrt{1-y^2}\right) = \cos^{-1}(y)-\cos^{-1}(x)\;,$$ because $(y<x)$

Now $$\displaystyle T_{k} = \cos^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{k+1}\right)-\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{k}\right)$$

So $$\displaystyle \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sum^{n}_{k=2}T_{k} = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left[\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{n+1}\right)-\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\right]$$

So we get $$\displaystyle \sum^{n}_{k=2}\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{(k-1)k(k+1)(k+2)}}
{k(k+1)}\right)= \cos^{-1}(0)-\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) = \frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\pi}{3} = \frac{\pi}{6}$$

So $$\displaystyle S_{n} = \frac{\pi}{6} = \frac{120\pi}{m}\;,$$ We get $$m=720$$

Comment: I thought it would be Riemann integral...but the solution awesome as ever :-)!! I don't think it can be converted to a Riemann integral either.

Comment: @juantheron ,elegant solution,Sir,as always.I need some tips on how to solidfy my subject on indefinite integrals,definite integrals,limits,functions.If you dont mind?